# What can I do to enhance the performance of bulk data loading using Derby?

Tags: performance, derby, bulkloader

I am using Derby In-Memory DB. I need to perform some data loading from csv files in the beginning. For now, it takes about 25 seconds to load all the csv files into their tables. I hope the time can be reduced. Due to the data files are not very large actually.

What I have done is using the built-in procedure from derby.

```
{CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE (?,?,?,',','"','UTF-8',1 )} or
{CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE (?,?,?,',','"','UTF-8',0 )}
```

The only special thing is sometimes the data in one tables is splitted into many small csv files. So I have to load them one by one.And I have tested if I can combine them together, it will only take 16 seconds. However I cannot remove this feature because it is needed by the user.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the time of loading data? Should I disable log or write some user-defined function/procedure or any other tune can be done? Any advice will be fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [H2](http://h2database.com) instead of Derby, and use the [CSVREAD](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv) feature. If that's still too slow, see the [fast import](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#fast_import) optimization, or use the [CSV tool](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Csv.html) directly (without using a database). Disclaimer: I wrote the CSV support for H2.

Comment: Right, I am also considering it. H2 is blazingly fast. :)

Comment: One question,will H2 take care of exporting Date type column to the correct format?,I remember it will only export using toString().Which is not so nicely.

Comment: I think the question is about import not export. For H2, use `CREATE TABLE .. (columnList) AS SELECT ... FROM CSVREAD`. That way, you have the correct data types.

Comment: As for export, use `CSVWRITE('SELECT ...',...)`. You can convert to any format you like in the `SELECT` column list part. The same when importing.

Comment: Yes, I asked this due to import/export function is for sure all needed. :) thanks for your nice answer. :)